# ReactJS this.props.history.push doesn't exists! this.props doesn't include history

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, missing-data, browser-history

Inside App.js I manage the routing (down below). In both classes I have

```
import {browserHistory} from "react-router";
```

As I click on the image the console shows up the error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. So my props doesn't include the history object. How to redirect the user using browserHistory?

```
////

    <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <div>
    <Route path="/profile" component={MyProfile} />
    </div
    </Router>

/// The code above is in a different class

    myprofile(props) {
        this.props.history.push('/profile');
    }

    return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <img src="../images/my-profile.png" alt="profile" className="myprofile" id="myprofile" onClick={this.myprofile.bind(this)} />
    </React.Fragment>
    );
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the component in [`withRouter()`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)?

Comment: No need for `this`, just `props.history.push`

Comment: The `props` param of `myprofile()` appears to be misnamed. It'll actually be the `event` from the `onClick` that calls it @Meir

Comment: It appears that you should be wrapping your `<img/>` tag with a [`<Link/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) component, rather than trying to navigate imperatively using `Router.push()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all your routers inside "BrowserRouter" Component also if you are trying to use the method this.history.push from a component which is not defined in your routes than you need to wrap that component with "withRouter(ComponentName)".